# How to check for multiple values of $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I have about 15 categories with different names and I'm using an if condition to check which value is coming. For example, one section contains cars, motors, parts, etc.; another contains jobs, jobs wanted, job offers, etc.

Here are example possible URLs:

- http://domain.com/subcatename=car
- http://domain.com/subcatename=motors

Instead of writing a condition for each possibility:

```
<?php if($_GET['subcatename'] == 'Cars')
// Show Car Form
//...
<?php if($_GET['subcatename'] == 'Motors')
// Show Motor Form
//...
```

I want to use code like this:

```
<?php if($_GET['subcatename'] == 'Cars,Motors') //Will this work ?
{
?>
// Show Motor Form If any of above value in url is appears, cars, motors or etc
<?php
}
?>
```

Or this:

```
if($_GET['catename'] = 'cars, motors, parts')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show some of your html too

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654155/get-post-data-from-multiple-checkboxes

Comment: `if($_GET['catename'] = 'cars, motors, parts')` Actually this is assignment not a condition...

Answer (score 4):

If you have the following html for your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catename[]" value="cars"> cars
<input type="checkbox" name="catename[]" value="motors"> motors
// etc
```

You can access it as an array (note it will likely be POST, not GET):

```
var_dump($_POST['catename']);
// array('cars', 'motors')
```

You can then use `in_array` to check for values:

```
if(in_array('cars', $_POST['catename'])) { ... }
```

Comment: What i want is to write one statement instead of multi statements like can i set something like that

Comment: if($_GET['catename'] = 'cars, motors, parts')

Comment: instead of writing if($_GET['catename'] = 'parts') { //something } or if($_GET['catename'] = 'cars') { //something }