# retrieving data from checkbox using php

Tags: php

i have send the value dynamically from check-box and when i tried to retrieve all the value dynamically using loop, it just goes on loading.
my code for sending value from check-box:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

   $member_id=$row["member_id"];
   <input type='checkbox' name='check' value='$member_id'>
}

// this is working. but when i try to fetch the data from checkbox from only where the tick is given it doesn't work. this is how i tried to fetch the data


while(isset($_POST['check']))
{
   echo $_POST['check']."<br>";

}
```

Comment: After editing your question I am worried a lot. Is that what you have in your php file. I am talking about the while loops code.

Comment: *"While `$_POST['check']` __is set__, output it, __then repeat__"*... How is this *not* an obvious infinite loop? Did you mean `if` instead of `while`?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654155/get-post-data-from-multiple-checkboxes

Comment: using if loop will only take one chekbox value but i need multiple. what can i do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is, when you have multiple checkboxes with the same name and you want to get all the checked values on the server side, then you need to add [] after the name of the checkbox field in the html, eg.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$member_id'>
```

if you do this, then $_POST['check'] will be an array of all the checked elements. As pointed out by others,

```
while(isset($_POST['check']))
```

represents an infinite loop. It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['check']))
foreach($_POST['check'] as $each_check)
 echo $each_check;
```

And finally, its a duplicate of  [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654155/get-post-data-from-multiple-checkboxes). Please search before asking again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
   $selections[] = $selected;
 }
 print_r($selections);
```

and change your html tag as :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value=".$member_id.">
```

Answer (score 0):

You added While loop, with the condition that will always true. So loop will become infinite.
Change you loop to foreach, like this

```
foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value)
{
  echo $value."<br>";
}
```

AND your check-boxes will not show till then you add `echo`, like this

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

  $member_id=$row["member_id"];
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='$member_id'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all the checkboxes

**WRONG WILL CAUSE INFINITE LOOP**

```
while(isset($_POST['check']))
{
    echo $_POST['check']."<br>";
}
```

One of the many correct alternatives:

```
foreach ($_POST['check'] as $val) {
     echo $val.'<br>';
}
```