# Adding a form array to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get the array put into the MySQL database in the format 'arrayitem1,arrayitem2,etc...'

Here's where my forms are:

```
<form action="http://www.nccskills.co.uk/bookings/process.php" method="post" name="bookingForm">
  <div id="row12">
    <div class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vocCheck[]" value="HASA">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;HEALTH AND SAFETY AWARENESS
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vocCheck[]" value="EAD">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;EQUALITY AND DIVERSITY
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row13">
    <div class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vocCheck[]" value="ECC">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;EFFECTIVE CUSTOMER CARE
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vocCheck[]" value="CC">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;CARE CERTIFICATE</div>
    </div>
```

What php would I use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use code blocks for longer sections of code in the future. Simply mark the text you want in the block and press the {} button. I have edited your question to do so now.

Comment: Thanks Anders, greatly appreciated. Any idea on the php side of it?

Comment: Yes. I posted an answer. If it is helpfull, please tick the checkmark to indicate that you acceptet it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `process.php` file you would want to have code that looks somewhat like this:

```
//Create a connection using MySQLi
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Prepare a statement.
$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename(fieldname) VALUES(?)');

//Put all the checkboxes together, if anything is selected.
$checked = '';
if(is_array($_POST['vocCheck'])) {
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['vocCheck']);
}

//Bind the value.
$conn->bind_param('s', $checked);

//Execute the question.
$conn->execute();
```

Not 100% sure you actually need to check if `$_POST['vocCheck']` is an array and I cant try right now so I included it just to be on the safe side. You might want to throw some error handling into that in case the connection doesn't work etc. Some useful links for you:

- [Get POST data from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654155/get-post-data-from-multiple-checkboxes)
- [PHP documentation on implode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)
- [Tutorial on hove to use PHP MySQLi](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)