# reading multiple values with same request-parameter name in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form:

```
<form>
  <input type='checkbox' name='element_1' value='1'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='element_1' value='2'/>
</form>
```

I check both boxes and submit the values to the server using jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'save.php',
              data: $('form').serialize(),
              success: function(){} 
            });
```

On the PHP server, I output the values:

```
var_dump( $_POST['element_1']);
```

but I only see the result:

```
string(1) "2"
```

Whereas I was expecting to see both values that were checked.

I can see both values in the Request headers from the client:

**X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest**
**Form Data**
element_1:1
element_1:2

Is there any way to retrieve both these values on the PHP server *without changing the client code?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get POST data from multiple checkboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654155/get-post-data-from-multiple-checkboxes)

Comment: IMO...its like a simple associative array... you cannot have 2 values with same array key.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use name array like multiple files uploads

```
<form>
  <input type='checkbox' name='element_1[]' value='1'/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='element_1[]' value='2'/>
</form>
```

Get data in PHP side using for or foreach loop.

Comment: `Is there any way to retrieve both these values on the PHP server without changing the client code?` did you read this?

Comment: No, @MKA this is not good practice as well as not allowed to use the same name for multiple elements in one form. The result will be overridden by last one.